Who is the angel described in Revelation 18:1?
I think I could spend a lifetime reading Revelation and still find new questions!  For today, this one:

And after these things I saw another angel come down from heaven, having great power; and the earth was lightened with his glory.

Revelation 18:1 - KJV
Is it possible to identify this angel?  Does it even matter?  What's notable about this passage in my mind is the parallel with an interesting O.T. passage in Ezekiel:

And, behold, the glory of the God of Israel came from the way of the east: and his voice was like a noise of many waters: and the earth shined with his glory.

Ezekiel 43:2 - KJV
I did a bit of Googling and Commentary hunting but didn't find much.

The angel of Rev. 18:1 is not specifically identified with Jesus. However, the idea that Christ was in fact an angel is supported in other NT scriptures. For example, as Prof. Bart Ehrman points out, Paul states in Galatians 4:14:

And my temptation which was in my flesh ye despised not, nor rejected;
but received me as an angel of God, even as Christ Jesus.

Many, however, reject the idea that Christ could be an angel, as well as being a man and (for trinitarians) the Second Person of the Trinity. Since it is identified as "another angel" - in other words not one of the seven angels mentioned in Revelation 15:1 - some suggest that this was the Angel of the LORD.  This begs the question as to whether the Angel of the LORD is identical with Jesus.
Conclusion: the identity of the angel of Rev. 18:1 is a matter of theological opinion. It could be Jesus, but it also could be the Angel of the LORD (presuming this angel is not Jesus) or some other unnamed powerful angel.

I upvoted that...it's careful and fair.

The following suggests that the Angel of Rev 18:1 is the Lord Jesus Christ or at least symbolically represents Him:

"great authority" is an allusion to Matt 28:18 where Jesus is given "all authority"
"the earth was illuminated by his glory" is an allusion to Jesus words in John 8:12 - "I am the light of the world".  See also Heb 1:2.
Jesus is consistently described as coming from heaven as per John 3:13, 31, 6:38, 6:46, 61, 62, 8:38, 13:1, 3, 16:27, 28, 17:5, etc.
The OT also confirms that Jesus is the "light" as per Ps 27:1, Eze 43:2 compare John 1:4, 5, 9, 8:12, 20:28.
Jesus is also described as "an Angel" = "messenger of God" - see appendix below.

APPENDIX - Jesus as the "Angel of God"
The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself, probably Jesus in particular.  Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, Rev 8:3-5, 10:1-10, 18:1, 20:1-4.
A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.
In Isa 63:9, “the Angel of His [LORD’s] presence saved them”, and is almost certainly a reference to the same being.  The same is true of Ex 23:20, 21, Josh 5:13-15.
In view of the clear statements in John 1:18, 5:37, 6:46, 1 John 4:12 that no one has seen God the Father, and the numerous cases listed above of people seeing the LORD and the Angel of the LORD, etc, it appears that these epiphanies were of the pre-incarnate Jesus.

Absolutely the same conclusion I was leaning towards but couldn't fing any mainline commentators saying this.  Also, wouldn't Hebrews 1 preclude Christ from being any kind of angel?

@Aleph-Gimel - Jesus is not an angel but God.  However, Jesus is the great messenger to humanity as the above references make clear.

right so would it be correct to say that Jesus is not an angel but that he is THE angel?

@Aleph-Gimel - yes - even the "Archangel" = ("leader of the angels").

But not Michael the archangel?

@Dottard. Your comment "Jesus is not an angel but God. However, Jesus is the great messenger to humanity"  messengers are not greater than the one who sent them. John 13:16. The apostles did not teach Jesus is the God of patriarchs Acts 3:13. Your answer "The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself, probably Jesus in particular." is an assumption. YHWH is not called angel. YHWH is not his own messenger.

Dottard - Jesus is the Angel of God. In Galatians 4:14, Paul states that Jesus is an angel of God. Malachi 3:1 calls Christ the Angel of the Covenant.

How many opinions about angels can dance on the head of pin? ;-)

@DanFefferman - Ha Ha!!  Good point  Perhaps this should be the subject of another question???
